# Excel VBA - Search for string in worksheet

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I've got this Excel Workbook which I want to search for a specific string in Sheet1. If it finds it, enter a new value. But, the sheet is pretty huge, so I don't think it would be very efficient to loop through each cell. So, can I search through a range and find it that way?

This is what I've got so far:

```
Dim rngSearchRange as range

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
      Set rngSearchRange = .Range("A2:A" & .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    End With
```

The string I'm looking for is the first value in an array of three values. So, how can I search this range for that specific string, find the position and then enter a new value?

I was thinking something along this:

```
Dim rngFindRange as range
Set rngFindRange = rngSearchRange.Find(var(0), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
```

The var(0) is the value in the array I'm after. But this line doesn't really give me any results. Am I way off here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like this

```
Sub FindMe()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngSearchRange As Range
    Dim rngFindRange As Range
    Dim Var
    Dim elemVar
    Var = Array("apples", "oranges", "fruit")
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Set rngSearchRange = ws.Range(ws.[a2], ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    For Each elemVar In Var
        Set rngFindRange = rngSearchRange.Find(elemVar, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
        If Not rngFindRange Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox elemVar & " found in " & rngFindRange.Address(0, 0)
        Else
            MsgBox elemVar & " not found in:"
        End If
    Next elemVar
End Sub
```

Comment: This seems logical. But I still don't get any results from the rngFindRange. Even though I can add the rngSearchRange as a watch and then look at the Cell.Formula(1) and see that the exact value there is the very same as in var(0).

Comment: Ok, just tried your code alone now. And it works find :) So, I need to look through my own code to see why this doesn't work. Edit. Seems as though it doesn't find anything if the string has a space in it? Edit2: that works as well. Hmm, I'll get back to you soon

Comment: What value are you searching for - an actual formula or the result of a formula? If the result of a formula  have you checked for any whitespaces in the values?

Comment: Yes, there aren't any white spaces at all. Strange enough, I can reassign the value of Val(0) with the exact same string as it already has. And it can find that! I do get the original string using an ADODB connection to a separate workbook though. Then I pull the values I wan't into the array. But that shouldn't matter should it?

Comment: Here's a screenshot: http://img641.imageshack.us/img641/4043/unledozi.png

Notice how the first rngFindRange is nothing. Then I assign the Var(0) the exact same value. And then it works! But, If I dim a new string variable, assign it to the original Var(0) and search for that, it doesn't find that either. So something happening to the strings in the array via the ADODB function most likely.

Comment: Just to clear up that last bit. It worked if I Dim a temp variable, assign that to the rs.GetRows. And then assign the real variable with t(0,0)